# Elisions in mathematics

Tags: math-mode, formatting, typography

Knuth incorporated many of the typographical rules for mathematics in the TeX engine. However some rules were left out. One such case is the use of elisions in equations. Sometimes `\cdots` are used and in other case `\ldots`.

In general, after examining a number of maths papers, I inferred the following "rules":

[image]

[image]

[image]

One could think of an `\xdots` type of command (similar to `\xspace` that could switch between the right type of ellipsis and allow the right space before and after it. A rough macro to do this is show in the MWE below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter

\def\xdots{%
  \newif\if@found
  \@foundfalse
  \def\ifPlus{\@ifnextchar+{\cdots}{\ifDot}}
  \def\ifDot{\@ifnextchar.{\ldots\@foundtrue}{\ifSemicolon}}
  \def\ifSemicolon{\@ifnextchar;{\cdots\@foundtrue}{\ifLeftBracket}}
  \def\ifLeftBracket{\@ifnextchar){\ldots\,\@foundtrue}{\ifOpenBracket}}
  \def\ifOpenBracket{\@ifnextchar({\dots\@foundtrue}{\ifNotFound}}
  \def\ifNotFound{\if@found\relax\else\ldots\fi}
  \ifPlus
}

\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{eqnarray*}
e^{xf(z)}-1
&=(z,z^2\!/2!,z^3\!/3!,\ldots\,)\,F\,(x,x^2,x^3,\xdots)^{\rm T}\\
\noalign{\smallskip}
e^{xg(z)}-1
&=(z,z^2\!/2!,z^3\!/3!,\ldots\,)\,G\,(x,x^2,x^3,\xdots)^{\rm T}
\end{eqnarray*}

\end{document}
```

`amsmath`  has what I consider  a partial solution with `\dots` and offers various commands for different cases.

Unfortunately this is not a trivial problem, as one needs to consider both the symbol before the ellipsis as well as the one that follows it. I am looking for suggestions, solutions and or strategies. I am also looking for "rules" that I might have missed in the above description.

Comment: There are more variants with `amsmath`, depending on the spacing: `\dotsc`, for an ellipsis followed by a comma. `\dotsb`, for an ellipsis followed by a binary operation or relation. `\dotsm`, for an ellipsis followed by multiplication. `\dotsi`, for an ellipsis with integrals, and `\dotso`, for another ellipsis.

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina Thanks, for sure but they are all translate back to the problem they are either `ldots` or `cdots` plus measures of spacing. In plain TeX you only get these and one has to fiddle the solution. This is why I was thinking of a programmatic solution.

Comment: @Yiannis: You know about `amsmath`'s automatic `\dots`, don't you?

Comment: @Hendrik Vogt, I do but they do not appear to be following all the rules, so people end up with `\dotsc` etc..

Comment: @Yiannis: Then it would be best if you tell that in the question, I guess. (And I just saw your chat message: It would be better if you perform that edit yourself `:-)`)

Comment: @Hendrik Vogt ... just added a small note.

Comment: @Yiannis : the result is better with `align` instead of `eqnarray`. With `align`, the spaces around `=` are fine

Comment: I don't think everyone follows your inferred rules. I for one disagree with rules 2, 3, and 4 at least. My general philosophy is that if the omitted items are "obviously" in a list, I use `\ldots`; if the omitted items are between binary operators (including the invisible implicit multiplication) I use `\cdots`; else whichever one looks better.

Comment: @Altermundus agreed, was getting late when I typed the above, will correct the image later.

Comment: @Willie Wong As you said one needs to choose whichever looks better, but my grandmother had different ideas as to what clothes looked better than my mother or my wife. The rules were inferred based on papers mostly typeset in the 80's as books published earlier were influenced by the typesetting equipment available. I haven't looked at anything post 2000. Why don't you list some different opinions and perhaps reasons.

Comment: michael spivak, in *joy of tex*, explains why `\dots` can't always "decide" what style of dots to use. specifically, the macro chooses the style based on what precedes and what follows. when `\dots` ends an expression, there is nothing following it, and a decision based solely on the immediately preceding symbol isn't always the most widely accepted choice. (notice that i didn't say "correct" -- it is sometimes a matter of opinion.) on p.152 (2nd edition) there is an example "where even right-thinking people may disagree on the use of dots" and on which spivak and knuth disagree.

Comment: I'm not really convinced this is actually a question. Any chance it can be edited to make it something which falls more clearly within the scope of the site?

Comment: @Joseph the question is really at the bottom, asking for ways to set these mathematical rules in a macro. So far no takers though:)

Comment: @Yiannis: sorry about late reply. I am still listless after the loss of my 'envelope'. `:-)` Anyway, my opinions are more or less the same as what drini wrote below, so I shan't bother to repeat them.

Comment: @Willie Wong I am sorry to hear about your `envelope`. Statistically most changes turn out to be for the better, you will see:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On items 3 and 4 you show, the proper usage would be  \cdots
since they are implied products (and operations become center) 
that'w why you have an "exception" on item 4 (since sums aren't implied, but shown explicitly)

Here's the quick ruleset

- A) Any comma-delimited listing (be in parentheses or not) becomes \ldot.
  Examples: Vectors, yor item 2
- B)  Any operator becomes \cdot.
  Examples:  sums, products (even implied), your item 1

  - Item 3 is therefore \cdots according to rule B
  - Item 4 is \cdots according  to rule B  (and exceptions disappear)
  - Item 5 as you show is \cdots, but not because it being fractions, but because it being operator (+). If you were listing a vector coordinates where each entry is a fraction, you would use \ldots according to rule A
  - Item 6 is special: I recommend using \cdots (there's no comman) and it is compatible with matrices where you may use \vdots for vertical elisions or \ddots for diagonal,  both of them being centered.
  - Item 7: Yes, subscripts and superscripts follow the same rules as if they were considered as expression by themselves